# Why can't you calculate a summary statistic on a series with .apply?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, apply, series

I'm experimenting with the .apply() method and noticed that Python doesn't seem to allow using it to calculate a summary statistic on a series.

You can use .apply() to modify all values in a series, e.g.,

```
test = pd.Series([1,2,3])

t_output = test.apply(lambda a : a *2)

t_output
```

yielding

[image]

However, if I wanted to generate a summary statistic, e.g.,

```
t_output2 = test.apply(np.sum)

t_output2
```

I just get the original series values:
[image]

I know I could instead write test.sum() and get the desired summary statistic. But I'm interested in better understanding the technical reason why .apply() doesn't seem to permit generating one for an isolated series.

I know that a series is size-immutable, but that shouldn't be consequential here because I'm reassigning the .apply() output to a new object. So any details on better understanding this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dataframe is two-dimensional, thus you can apply some functionality along either dimension (i.e. on either rows or columns). As a series is one-dimensional, the functionality is applied on each element (i.e. value) of the series. Of course, if the entries of the series themselves have dimensions, then summation could be a useful function to apply, but if they are just numbers, applying summation is just the identity, as there is no dimension to summarize (i.e. sum) over.

Comment: Thanks! This does make me wonder though why writing test.sum() would yield the sum of all rows in the series (6). Using the .sum() method seems to be able to do summation on each element of the series.

Does this/your answer have something more to do with applying a function (through a method: .apply()) versus just applying a method directly?

Comment: A series has no rows in that sense. Maybe you are confusing the series entries (which consist of an index (to the left) and a value (to the right)) with a row?

Comment: I think I wasn't quite making the connection between single-dimension and single-axis. I think the general description of a series as a single-dimension object, without further explanation, can be a bit misleading, as there is seemingly an index- and non-index column. But I'm seeing what you're saying now! I found this source particularly helpful in unpacking what's meant by one-dimensionality: https://medium.com/data-science-365/pandas-for-data-science-part-1-89bc231b3478. Since .apply() runs on axes, it makes sense that using .apply() on a series would be restricted to one axis.